# How to access cookie in grails2.2.5 service

Tags: grails, cookies

I can't get cookie value from grails service,
i am using code like this

```
g.cookie(name: 'cookieName')
```

I got an error

```
Unable to resolve g
```

How can i fix this

Comment: retrieve the data you need from the cookie inside your Controller and pass that value as a parameter to your service-method

Answer (score 1):

Most of the grails' Controller entities are not exposed to services, for a reason: it does not belong there. Same reason why you can't use `message(code: ..)` in a service. Also, cookies exists whenever request exists which is not something that you can have in a service. Some background job could call your service for example. Your BootStrap could make a service call when application starts. Its simply not on the http-layer.

You could pass your `request` (HttpServletRequest) to your service in a method call and then in the service use `getCookies()` or similar method, or you can do all http-related stuff in a Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive current request in service: `WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getCurrentRequest()`
And there will be field `cookies` as Array